# How to get a single array return value in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, aggregate

I'm using Nodejs, Typescript and Mongodb. I take a nested array in my query but i only want to get a single array from db. My query is :

```
let sampleQuery:any = await   OfferModel.aggregate([
                    {$match : {CompanyLoginMail : CompanyLoginMail}},
                    {$lookup: {from: "members",localField: "MiddleManMail",foreignField: "Email",as: "mems"}},
                    {$project : {
                            mems : { $filter : {input : "$mems"  , as : "mems", cond : { $ne : ['$$mems.Email' , CompanyLoginMail]}} }


                        }}

                ])
                return sampleQuery;
```

I get this from mongodb:

```
[
    {
        [
            {},{},{}
        ]
    }
]
```

But i want this:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

Comment: What does a document in the members collection look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        mems: [
            {},{},{}
        ]
    }
]
```

you need two additional pipeline stages, [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$mems" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$mems" } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EiXF8UO1yqH)

Comment: Thank you, i will try and give feedback.

Comment: Yes it works, this is the solution. Thank you again @mickl